# What is the blood point cost of using Obfuscate in V20?

Tags: world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade

I was reading through *Vampire: the Masquerade* 20th Anniversary edition, and while reading up on Obfuscate I couldn't find a mention of a blood cost at all, except for on the level 3 power Mask the Unseen where it says the character may appear more attractive by spending “more” blood points. More than what though? There doesn't seem to be any cost with it. Can anyone tell me if I am seeing it right?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### None.

You are correct. Disciplines don't cost blood to use unless they say they do.

> **Note:** Unless stated in the description, Disciplines cost no blood or Willpower points to activate. (p.128)

Comment: This answer is correct in general, especially in ruling that other Obfuscate powers cost no blood. But, to round out the answer,  the description in question (for Obfuscate 3) from V20 says that the cost of the power (if any) is the difference between the appearance rating of the illusion and the discipline user's. So a Nosferatu (appearance 0) using the power to copy the face of someone with an Appearance rating of 3 would have to pay 3 blood (3 additional points beyond the normal 0 for the power). Reference: V20, p. 185.

Comment: @Upper_Case Sure, but that's already accounted for in the first sentence of the question.

Comment: The mechanic is mentioned, but the actual cost is not. Also, and this may just be my read, but the phrasing of the question makes it seem plausible that this is one of WW's "leave it to the Storyteller's discretion" situations, which it is not. Again, great answer (+1!), I just wanted to add enough information that this question is a complete reference.